# Strokefont Stroke Color Overwritten after setColor()

Tags: android, andengine

I have some Text that I sometimes want to have a black outline, and sometimes green. I thought I could accomplish this by having two StrokeFonts, one with black outline, and one with a green outline, and then when I instantiate my `Text` object I just use the font I want.

The problem is that after that, I ALSO need to set the main color (inside, not stroke) of the font based on other conditions. While my logic works, when I do `setColor()` the stroke always is black, rendering my first logic useless.

Is there something I'm missing here, or another way to get around this? I have commented out the `setColor()` calls after I decide which StrokeFont to use and I see the stroke properly, so I know it's getting overwritten with the `setColor()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Set color multiplies the value of the existing color. So black (value 0)  will never change color. But white will become any color you want. 
So if you want to make a sprite or text that will assume any color, it has to start out as white.

I think you may still have a problem though, since the stroke of the stroke font is drawn to the same texture as the fill, so that any color adjustment made to the stroke will equally tint the fill.

You're either goiuing to need more Fonts, or choose another way to render them, such as using an outline font and a fill font to that you are actually displaying two Text objects.
Either way, you should be able to find your way if you understand that setColor multiplies the values times the existing value.

Comment: I know about using white so that the color can be changed. But basically the issue is that setColor() seems to do this multiplication and changing the stroke color, even if you don't want that. Is there a way around that? There honestly should be a setStrokeColor() or something in the API. Sounds like I'd have to modify source. I'll upvote your answer because of the multiplication of colors info.

Comment: The thing is that the stroke is not added at runtime. Its drawn onto the texture. So when you setColor() on a font, the stroke is part of the same texture. You can't tint a texture selectively by pixel. What you need to do is make your own bitmap fonts, one of the stroke and one of the fill, and not rely on the StrokeFont to get the effect you want. Then whenever you display stroke text, there are actually two layered Texts one of the Stroke font, and one of the fill. You will be able to setColor() on each text object individually. To the user it will look like on text field.

Comment: That my friend is a good idea. When you say "my own bitmap font" I assume you mean like my own Java class that marries two fonts/two `Text` objects in AndEngine together into a single entity that I can then control independently like I want. That's really a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to creating a bitmap font (.fnt) that is compatible with the BitmapFont class in Andengine. You can create and customize them using image editng software and this program: http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/ (PC only and FREE) or this one: http://www.71squared.com/en/glyphdesigner (Mac only and about $40 USD) - but your understanding of the rest of the suggestion was spot on.